# Helm yaml arrays values that sometimes requires spaces/tabs but sometimes not?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am confused when to use spaces and when not to when it comes to arrays and configs.

I think for single value arrays you need to use spaces:

ie:

```
values:
  - "hello"
  - "bye"
  - "yes"
```

However this is wrong:

```
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: sb-testing
  minReplicaCount: 3
  triggers:
    - type: azure-servicebus
    metadata:
      direction: in
```

When the values are a map, the helm interpreter complains when I add spaces:
`error: error parsing deploy.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 12: did not find expected '-' indicator`

Doesn't when I don't:

```
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: sb-testing
  minReplicaCount: 3
  triggers:
  - type: azure-servicebus
    metadata:
      direction: in
```

I can't seem to find any rules about this.

Comment: The [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) is dense, but it at least has lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of objects in YAML can start with or without spaces. Both are valid in YAML syntax.

```yaml
values:
 - "hello"
 - "bye"
 - "yes"
```

```yaml
values:
- "hello"
- "bye"
- "yes"
```

Make sure that the keys of the same block must be in the same column.

Sample:

```yaml
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: sb-testing
  minReplicaCount: 3
  triggers:
    - type: azure-servicebus 
      metadata: # "metadata" and "type" in the same column 
        direction: in
```

or

```yaml
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: sb-testing
  minReplicaCount: 3
  triggers:
  - type: azure-servicebus
    metadata:
      direction: in
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. Is there a spec or rules page for this? I've never seen anyone talk about this before. This wasn't part of the question, but I've seen double dashes too, what is that about?.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_indentation_and_separation.htm